# Processing JSON Response in Scala play WS

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I would like to process the following JSON response:

```
[ 
   { 
      "name":"xxx1",
      "format":"xxx2",
      "type":"xxx3",
      "url":"xxx4"
   },
   { 
      "name":"yyy1",
      "format":"yyy2",
      "type":"yyy3",
      "url":"yyy4"
   }
]
```

I am tying to write the related code, but I am stuck here:

```scala
  case class Repository(repoName: String, repoFormat: String, repoType: String, repoURL: String)
  case class RepositoryList(repositoryList: List[Repository])

  implicit val repoReads = Reads[Repository] = (
    (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "format").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "type").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "url").read[String]
  )(Repository.apply _)

  implicit val repoListReads = Reads[RepositoryList] = (
    (???).read[Seq[Repository]]
  )(RepositoryList.apply _)

request.get().map(response => Ok((response.json).validate[RepositoryList]))
```

What comes to the "???" part? It is basically a list of JSONs, there is no attribute on that level.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pragmatic solution would be just to use `List[Repository]` and then create a `RepositoryList`:

```
request.get()
   .map(response => 
        Ok(
           (response.json).validate[List[Repository]]
              .map(RepositoryList)
        )
    )
```

Check [scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/0dVTZfz/1)

Comment: In this case I get the following compilation error:
Cannot write an instance of play.api.libs.json.JsResult[HomeController.this.RepositoryList] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[play.api.libs.json.JsResult[HomeController.this.RepositoryList]]

Comment: I had to add .toString after ".map(RepositoryList)". Now it works! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of using `validate[RepositoryList]` and avoiding the extra map after validate, using Reads.list composition would do the trick.  So the ??? could be replaced with

```
implicit val repoListReads: Reads[RepositoryList] = Reads.list[Repository].map(RepositoryList)
```

and you can call
`response.json.validate[RepositoryList]`